# How can I check if the Length is less than 2 in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have two dashes in my cell, I am trying to check after second dashes how many characters. If the length or character more than two then delete the row.

```
   Sub fi()

   Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, firstD As Integer, secondD As Integer, bpno As Long

   lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
       For i = 1 To lastrow
          firstD = InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1), "-")
          secondD = InStr(firstD + 1, ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1), "-")
          bpno = Mid(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1), firstD + 1, secondD - firstD)

            If Len(bpno) > 1 Then
              MsgBox ("yes")
            End If

       Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to walk the rows backwards to keep row numbers in sync within your loop.

Assuming there are always 2 dashes use InStrRev to get the offset of the last one & compare to the length:

```
For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1
    value= ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
    If Len(value) - InStrRev(value, "-") > 2 Then ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Delete
Next
```